# Expectation Problem.

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation

What's wrong with the first 2. If substitution of variable is what we are doing then it should be 1. I'm unable to get why only 3rd one is correct. Please help.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjbbk.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with probability mass function $p(x)$. Then the expected value of a function $f(x)$ (if it is defined) is $\mathbb{E}[f(x)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)p(x)dx$. In your case, $f(x)=x^2$, hence only the third formula in your notes is correct.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your answer. Can you please tell me why it isn't p(f(x)) because probability should be on probability mass function, not x.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "probability should be on probability mass function". Probability of your random variable is uniquely determined by probability mass function. And the expected value is simply defined as above, there is nothing to explain. Hope I could help.